# Z-index infront of object but still keep the objects function

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, z-index, navbar

I got a navbar controlled by css working very fine with a hover effect,
The problem is that I have a link I can't do anything about and I want that link to be on top of the navbar without disabling the hover effect. That link got a dropdown menu attached to it that I want to keep. 
The reason I can't do anything about this link is because I am using a design platform
works like this:
Edit -> Toprow Objects: Navmenu (the link) - HTML document ( my navbar ) - searchfield. 
(I modify the look by inserting objects)
I thought I figured it all out when I discovered z-index.
however when I put the code like this:

```
.main-nav-top {
    background: black url("picture");
    border-bottom: 1px solid #a4a4a4;
    border-top: 1px solid #a4a4a4;
    height: 47px;
    width: 1070px;
position:absolute;
left:0px;
top:0px;
z-index:-1;
}
```

the dropdown works verywell but the hover effects dissapears

When I put the code like this:

```
.main-nav-top {
    background: black url("Picture");
    border-bottom: 1px solid #a4a4a4;
    border-top: 1px solid #a4a4a4;
    height: 47px;
    width: 1070px;
position:absolute;
left:0px;
top:0px;
z-index:+1;
}
```

The hover works very well but the link with dropdown dissapears.
Is there some way I can get this fixed?

Comment: Is the positioning (e.g absolute, relative) the same on both of the elements? If not, Z-index won't apply?

Comment: it's set to absolute on the css that controls the navbar, ( unmarked, hovered, marked )

Answer (score 0):

Well, for this you can't do anything except for creating another element over it and make it visible after say 0.1s (so your animations still work). When the new element will become visible, it will replace the animated one, hence, fooling the people.